# How to read multiple strings in C one in a line, each containing spaces?

Tags: c, string, malloc, c-strings, gets

I allocated a 2D array of characters, and while reading strings with no whitespaces between, the code is working fine. When I read them with whitespaces, I'm facing a bug. How do I read all N number of Strings, each in a single line, each one containing whitespaces.

### Example input:

```
Enter total number of Strings : 3

Enter all the 3 Strings :

John Doe

Jane Doe

Trad Braversy
```

### My code:

```
// Code to enter the total number of Strings : 
int N;
printf("\n\tEnter the total number of Strings : ");
scanf("%d", &N);

// Code for allocating initial memory to them :
char** strings = (char**)malloc(N * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    strings[i] = (char*)malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
}

// Code for entering all the N strings :
printf("\n\tEnter all the %d Strings :\n", N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    gets(strings[i]);
}

// Code to reallocate the memory according to the entered length :
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    strings[i] = (char*)realloc(strings[i], strlen(strings[i]) + 1);
}
```

Comment: And does the code you presented work? Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: *Never* use `gets`.  I think I'm going to do some archeology to figure out when that advice became common knowledge, and I'd be surprised if the final answer is anytime after 1981.  But finding data that far back might be difficult.

Comment: @KamilCuk It does if I enter Strings without spaces between them. If I give N = 3, and start scanning Strings with spaces, it scans a 2 and remaining code is getting executed , the other String isn't getting scanned.

Comment: @xing No, I added a prompt above the loop, saying : "Enter all the N Strings : ", even after that the code is working the same.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Unfortunately, the book "Let us C" is still very popular in India. I took a glance in that book and it was truly horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few observations:

It's safer to read a full line of text, then parse out the integer from that, rather than doing `scanf()` for a single integer. This is because the latter leaves the newline in the stream, which can confuse later reads.

There's no real point in using `malloc()` to do dynamic memory allocation for this, you can use a VLA:

```
char strings[N][1024];
```

Note that using a capital-only symbol for a runtime variable is stylistically strange in C.

Then, it's *much* better to use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets), it's safer and just better:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
  if (fgets(strings[i], sizeof strings[i], stdin) == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "**Read error on string %d\n", i);
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

And as always, be prepared that I/O can fail, and try to handle that.

Comment: Okay, I won't use Dynamic Memory Allocation. But what if my string isn't 1024 characters long? Won't it be like wasting a lot of memory?

Comment: @RahulSriRam Probably it would. But in your reference code you alloc ANYWAY 1024 characters. So your are wasting heap memory. It would have been different if you had malloc'ed the expected length + 1 chars.

Comment: @RahulSriRam — how many gigabytes of memory does your machine gave?  How many kilobytes are you in danger of wasting?  Is the waste a significant fraction of the total available?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I realloc'ed each string to their string length using another loop after reading the strings. So I don't think I am wasting any space. I didn't add that do the code above, I am editing now.

Comment: @RahulSriRam and why don't you simply ONE `temp` string 1024 bytes long and then copy it to a newly allocated buffer `strlen(temp)+1` bytes big? In this way you will not have an heap wasting for a big value of N.

Comment: Using gets() to read the integer and then typecasting it using atoi(), and parallelly using fgets() and fputs() made the code work. Thanks for the suggestion @unwind.

Comment: @RahulSriRam Glad it helped. One minor nit: in C, type casting is static, i.e. you can't call a function to do a type cast. A type cast always looks like `(type)` before an expression. What `atoi()` does is converting, or parsing, or interpreting, etc.